# Unable to load CS project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, msbuild

I have downloaded [NetTopologySuite](https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite) from Github. I am failing to load it in my Visual Studio 2015 IDE.

> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\src\NetTopologySuite\NetTopologySuite.csproj
> : error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the
> MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
> format, please add
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
> 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\src\NetTopologySuite\NetTopologySuite.csproj
>
> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\test\NetTopologySuite.Samples.Console\NetTopologySuite.Samples.Console.csproj
> : error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the
> MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
> format, please add
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
> 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\test\NetTopologySuite.Samples.Console\NetTopologySuite.Samples.Console.csproj
>
> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\test\NetTopologySuite.TestRunner\NetTopologySuite.TestRunner.csproj
> : error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the
> MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
> format, please add
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
> 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\test\NetTopologySuite.TestRunner\NetTopologySuite.TestRunner.csproj
>
> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\src\NetTopologySuite.TestRunner.Console\NetTopologySuite.TestRunner.Console.csproj
> : error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the
> MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
> format, please add
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
> 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\src\NetTopologySuite.TestRunner.Console\NetTopologySuite.TestRunner.Console.csproj
>
> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\test\NetTopologySuite.Tests.Vivid.XUnit\NetTopologySuite.Tests.Vivid.XUnit.csproj
> : error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the
> MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
> format, please add
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
> 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\test\NetTopologySuite.Tests.Vivid.XUnit\NetTopologySuite.Tests.Vivid.XUnit.csproj
>
> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\test\NetTopologySuite.Tests.NUnit\NetTopologySuite.Tests.NUnit.csproj
> : error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the
> MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
> format, please add
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
> 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\test\NetTopologySuite.Tests.NUnit\NetTopologySuite.Tests.NUnit.csproj
>
> C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\src\NetTopologySuite.Lab\NetTopologySuite.Lab.csproj
> : error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the
> MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003
> format, please add
> xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the
>  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or
> 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  C:\Users\pc\Desktop\GIS
> Suite\NetTopologySuite-develop\NetTopologySuite-develop\src\NetTopologySuite.Lab\NetTopologySuite.Lab.csproj

Then I tried to ***NetTopologySuite.csproj*** only by deleting all other folders.

[image]

So, I changed file into the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <NoWarn>659,168,1587</NoWarn>
    <EnableApiCompat>true</EnableApiCompat>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Label="Assembly Info">
    <AssemblyTitle>NetTopologySuite</AssemblyTitle>
    <Description>A .NET library for GIS operations, direct porting of JTS Topology Suite $(JTSCompatibilityLevel) library</Description>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Label="NuGet Package Info">
    <PackageId>NetTopologySuite</PackageId>
    <Title>NTS - Topology Suite</Title>
    <Authors>NetTopologySuite - Team</Authors>
    <Owners>NetTopologySuite - Team</Owners>
    <PackageLicenseExpression>BSD-3-Clause</PackageLicenseExpression>
    <PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>true</PackageRequireLicenseAcceptance>
    <Description>The NTS Topology Suite is an API for modelling and manipulating 2-dimensional linear geometry. It provides numerous geometric predicates and functions. NTS conforms to the Simple Features Specification.</Description>
    <PackageTags>NTS;Topology;OGC;SFS</PackageTags>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Memory" Version="4.5.3" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(EnableApiCompat)' == 'true' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.DotNet.ApiCompat" Version="5.0.0-beta.20162.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageDownload Include="NetTopologySuite" Version="[$(NtsMajorVersion).0.0]" PrivateAssets="All" />

    <ResolvedMatchingContract Include="$(NugetPackageRoot)nettopologysuite\$(NtsMajorVersion).0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\NetTopologySuite.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

[image]

So, it is not working.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: VS 2015 does not support .net core 2. You can try VS 2017.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unable to load CS project in Visual Studio 2015

Your project seems to be a new sdk format project(**Net Core** and **Net Standard**).

It uses `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` rather than the traditional project style:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

And **VS2015** does not support the new sdk style project.

Since **VS2017**, **Microsoft** Released the new sdk style project(`net core` and `net standard`). You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/resources/check-project-format).

=============

**Also**, what you modified is also new sdk format format(`Microsoft.NET.Sdk`) and you wrote it in a mistake.

**Net Standard** project cannnot use the old style format:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
```

**Solution**

So you should download to use **VS2017** or **VS2019**.

Also, when you install it by vs installer, you should make sure that you have installed **Net Core** workload:

Check both of them.

[image]

[image]

**In my side**, I can open the project from the github.

Comment: We actually stopped watching VS2017 compatibility in NetTopologySuite a little while ago: https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/commit/d501e664751599e9bfefbdf062d665ef135d2ac1, and I think VS2017 will run into errors when you try to build the tests: they target .NET Core 3.1, which I believe causes errors when you try to use it in VS2017.